# Why does an error occur when redefining an interface?

Tags: flutter, dart

why Error in @override flutter class?
I am new to flutter.
Please tell me what is my mistake? I use a class so that there is no code repetition, but it swears at @override
Code below -

```
class Navigator extends StatelessWidget {

  final String nameButton;
  final String navigation;
  const Navigator(this.nameButton, this.navigation)
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 220,
      height: 55,
      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
        context.go('/$navigation}');
      }, child: Text(nameButton, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: StadiumBorder(), primary: Colors.cyan),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

error -

```
Const constructors can't have a body.  Try removing either the 'const' keyword or the body.
A function body must be provided.  Try adding a function body.
```

Comment: Add ";" at the end of `const Navigator(this.nameButton, this.navigation)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this? You need to remove const

```
Navigator(this.nameButton, this.navigation);
```